# The @RepeatedTest does not start

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit5

For example we have the[`@RepeatedTest`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-repeated-tests):

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.RepeatedTest;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

class SomeClassTest {
    @RepeatedTest(3)
    public void doSmth() {
        String str = "hello";
        SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
        assertEquals(str.substring(0, 2), someClass.doSmth(str));
    }
}
```

It works fine until we will try to run it from the [Test Suite](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-junit-platform-runner-test-suite) like this:

```
import org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasses;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@SelectClasses({
        SomeClassTest.class
})
public class TestSuite {
}
```

`SomeClass`

```
public class SomeClass {
    public String doSmth(String str){
        return str.length() > 3? str.substring(0,2) : str;
    }
}
```

No errors in the console. The test just won't start. **Why?**

[image: problem]

---

**Update**

I enabled logging in `SomeClass`.

```
public class SomeClass {
    private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeClass.class.getName());
    public String doSmth(String str){
        log.info("in doSmth");
        return str.length() > 3? str.substring(0,2) : str;
    }
}
```

Now I see in log-file that `@RepeatedTest` was called from the Test Suite 3 times. But what happens with the test later? Why does it fall?

Can anyone tell me if there is a possibility to log the work of the JUnit?

Comment: What version of IntelliJ are you using?

Comment: Your code works fine for me in Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.1a. So there is nothing wrong with the setup or JUnit Jupiter. Thus, it's likely an issue with the version of IntelliJ you're using.

Comment: @SamBrannen thanks for clarification! I use `IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5
Build #IU-172.4343.14, built on September 26, 2017` with 
`JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b12 amd64; JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o`

Comment: Try following the guidelines here to see if it's a compatibility issue: http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-ide-intellij-idea

Answer (score 0):

You can log the repeated test execution details with the following stub in your `SomeClassTest` class as:-

```
private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SomeTest.class.getName());

@BeforeEach
void beforeEach(TestInfo testInfo, RepetitionInfo repetitionInfo) {
    log.info(String.format("About to execute repetition %d of %d for %s",
              repetitionInfo.getCurrentRepetition(), 
                repetitionInfo.getTotalRepetitions(), 
                 testInfo.getTestMethod().get().getName()));
}
```

Also with the current logic, I don't see a reason why the test would `FAIL` or else you can face an assertion error that you must end up with for failure cases.

Comment: Thanks, but I mean logging internal work of JUnit. For example if I want to log Hibernate work I paste into `logback.xml` one line – `<logger name="org.hibernate" level="ERROR" />`. _"I don't see a reason why the test would FAIL"_ – Me too. But it fails. Just run the code yourself and you will see.